# how to get shutter actuation count from image metadata android

Tags: android, image, metadata, photography, shutter

I am using metadata-extractor-2.5.0-RC3.jar to extract metadata from an image.
It shows all the details except shutter count.
It there any possibility to get all metadata from an image

```
private void prosessImage(Uri uri) {
    try {
        // InputStream is = new URL(uri);
        InputStream is = null;

        is = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        // Convert your stream to data here
        // is.close();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        Metadata metadata = ImageMetadataReader.readMetadata(bis, true);
        JSONArray data = new JSONArray();
        for (Directory directory : metadata.getDirectories()) {
            for (Tag tag : directory.getTags()) {

                System.out.println(tag);
                data.put(tag);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(data);
        // JSONArray dictionary = new JSONArray();

    } catch (ImageProcessingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

hi everyone i find the tag for shutter count

"[Nikon Makernote] Exposure Sequence Number - 7733",

Comment: Hi. What was the tag?

Comment: Exposure Sequence Number